# join and order with mysql unions

Tags: mysql

I'd be grateful if someone could help me with this. I have two simple tables and I would like to create a (not so simple) query. One of my tables stores user data, the another one stores messages sent between users. Like these:

```
TABLE1
userid, username
0, Alice
1, Bob
2, Tom
3, Jerry

TABLE2
messageid, senderid, recipientid, message
0, 3, 2, "Hello Tom, how are you?"
1, 2, 3, "Hello Jerry"
2, 2, 0, "Happy Birthday Alice, Hugs, Tom"
3, 3, 1, "Bob, what's up there?"
```

I would like to create a contact list of any given user. I mean, an ordered list that includes the names of users who got messages from the given user or sent messages to him/her. So the contact list of Tom would look like this:

```
Alice
Jerry
```

And Bob's contact list would include Jerry only. And so on.

I figured out that maybe I have to use two select operations and union them. For example:

```
(select senderid from TABLE2 where recipientid=2) 
union 
(select recipientid from TABLE2 where senderid=2)
```

I have three questions.

How can I use JOIN here to see the names from TABLE1 instead of ids from TABLE2?

How can I sort the result by the names?

And, is it possible to solve this in any other way?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested it, but this query should give you Tom's contact list.

```
 SELECT DISTINCT t1.username
     FROM table1 t1 JOIN (
         SELECT senderid AS userid, recipientid AS contactid FROM table2
         UNION
         SELECT recipientid as userid, senderid as contactid from table2
     ) t2 on t1.userid = t2.contactid
     WHERE t2.userid = 2
     ORDER BY t1.username
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select userId, userName
from
  ((select senderid as userId from TABLE2 where recipientid=2) 
    union 
  (select recipientid as userId from TABLE2 where senderid=2) as innerView)
join TABLE1
where innerView.userid = TABLE1.userid
```

I'm rusty and usually use Oracle which has some differences to standard sql but idea should hold even if my syntax is a little off.

Answer (score 0):

I have not executed it, but I hope this suits your requirements.

```
SELECT T1.username AS sender, T2.Receiver AS Receiver
FROM
  table1 T1,
  (SELECT table1.username AS receiver FROM table1,table2
   WHERE table2.senderid = table1.userid AND table1.userid = t1.userid
  ) AS T2
WHERE T1.username = 'Tom';
```